# Print R output and don't print R code in org-mode exported to LaTeX

Tags: r, emacs, latex, org-mode, ess

I have the following in a file called `test.org`

```
#+begin_src R :session
  mod = lm(disp ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
  summary(mod)
#+end_src
```

What I want to do is run LaTeX on this document and export it to a PDF. I want to suppress the input and only print the output in the PDF. I don't know the arguments I need to pass to the code block. Can someone help? Also, if you find this in documentation, please let me know where so I can read it.

EDIT:
I can get something close to what I want by doing the following:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:R  :session :exports results :results output latex
#+begin_src R 
  mod = lm(disp ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
  xtable::xtable(summary(mod))
#+end_src
```

However, is it possible to achieve this without using `xtable::xtable()` or is this a limitation of org-mode?

Comment: org-mode doesn't come equipped with a generic R output -> latex converter [which doesn't exist AFAIK]. R's generic print function is flexible enough that output could be anything. You could try alternative functions that produce latex formatted tabular output, akin to `xtable` however

Comment: Not a `org-mode` feature, more like `pandoc`, but you can have a look at `codebraid` project. This should allow you to generate `pdf` from your source (eventhough some experimentations had to be done), provided that your source is not very feature-heavy (well, not everything is supported with `pandoc`).

Comment: Thanks the both you of you for these tips. It looks like I'll probably justwrap output in `xtable` or a similar package.